# How to connect to ElastiCache cluster using node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis, amazon-elasticache

> We know that [ElastiCache is not recommended to be accessed outside Amazon instances](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21937214/2404470), so we're trying below stuff inside Amazon EC2 instances only.

We've got a [ElastiCache Redis Cluster](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/Clusters.html) with 9 nodes. When we try to connect to it using [normal redis implementation](https://github.com/xameeramir/redisTest), it throws [some Moved errors](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/179)

Have tried the [retry strategy method](https://github.com/xameeramir/redisClusterTest/blob/master/startRedisTest.js) as per [@Miller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35044722/2404470). Have also tried [RedisCluster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-cluster) with [unstable](https://github.com/xameeramir/redisClusterTest/blob/master/startRedisClusterTest.js) and [stable (poor man)](https://github.com/xameeramir/redisClusterTest/blob/master/startPoorMansClusterClient.js) implementations.

None of these implementations are working. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> [Sharing the code](https://github.com/nordible/redisClusterTest/blob/master/startRedis-ClustrTest.js) for future readers:

```
var RedisClustr = require('redis-clustr');
var RedisClient = require('redis');
var config = require("./config.json");

var redis = new RedisClustr({
    servers: [
        {
            host: config.redisClusterHost,
            port: config.redisClusterPort
        }
    ],
    createClient: function (port, host) {
        // this is the default behaviour
        return RedisClient.createClient(port, host);
    }
});

//connect to redis
redis.on("connect", function () {
  console.log("connected");
});

//check the functioning
redis.set("framework", "AngularJS", function (err, reply) {
  console.log("redis.set " , reply);
});

redis.get("framework", function (err, reply) {
  console.log("redis.get ", reply);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this but it is not working for me. What configuration of elasticache redis did you use?

Comment: @Ultrablendz please check the link again! I have updated it

Comment: Thanks for updating the link, however, it is not working with AWS Elastiredis with cluster mode enabled. I am also trying to it out from a lamda instance and not ec2 instance, though that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Can you please suggest way for including auth, I have encryption in transit on elasticache instance, which I am not able to authenticate using client.auth, code just dies there, I am sure I am missing something and couldn't find anything over internet

Comment: @SalimShamim please post a new question!

Comment: @ZameerAnsari I am not able to connect to cluster using the code you provided. It is giving timeout errors.

Comment: @AvaniKhabiya Check if you've provided the correct host and port

Comment: @ZameerAnsari It's the right host and port I have provided. What could be the issue in this case?

Comment: @AvaniKhabiya If all the details provided in my solution match your problem then it's possible that this answer is outdated. I would suggest asking a new question with the steps to reproduce the problem

Comment: I added this code it worked with me, however, I got an error with elasticache cluster mode, some case it makes the website return a 404 page because Redis redirect node

Comment: @tomnyson I no longer work on this project so I'm not sure how to fix it. Can you please figure out the solution and update this answer??

Answer (score 1):

You can try to connect using ioredis.

```js
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var config = require("./config.json");

const redis = new Redis({
  host: config.host,
  port: config.port,
  password: config.password, // If you have any.
  tls: {}, // Add this empty tls field.
});

redis.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('Redis client is initiating a connection to the server.');
});

redis.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('Redis client successfully initiated connection to the server.');
});

redis.on('reconnecting', () => {
  console.log('Redis client is trying to reconnect to the server...');
});

redis.on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));

//check the functioning
redis.set("framework", "AngularJS", function(err, reply) {
  console.log("redis.set ", reply);
});

redis.get("framework", function(err, reply) {
  console.log("redis.get ", reply);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const redisClient = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
  ? new Redis.Cluster(
    [
      {
        host: 'node-production-0001-001.b2tyw0.0001.use2.cache.amazonaws.com',
        port: 6379,
        flags: 'master'
      },
      {
        host: 'node-production-0001-002.b2tyw0.0001.use2.cache.amazonaws.com',
        port: 6379,
        flags: 'slave'
      },
      {
        host: 'node-production-0001-003.b2tyw0.0001.use2.cache.amazonaws.com',
        port: 6379,
        flags: 'slave'
      },
    ], {
      scaleReads: 'slave'
    }
  )
  : new Redis({
    host: process.env.REDIS_HOST || 'localhost',
    port: process.env.REDIS_PORT || 6379,
  });
```

It's work for me with enable cluster mode

Comment: which npm package you have imported ? I have imported "redis" package.  I got error: TypeError: Redis.Cluster is not a constructor